# "Lock down" app on BlackBerry PlayBook to prevent navigation away?

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I was wondering if its possible to lock an app so that the user can't select any hardware buttons to get out of the app.

The app will be used for display purposes at a conference and want to display a video constantly. When finished the app can be closed from within the app by entering a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no API available to third-party developers to do this.

It seems likely RIM will eventually provide one, but they've said nothing publicly about it one way or the other.  I'd suggest contacting them to ensure they're aware of your desire for this and the specific use case, so they can factor that into their priorities.

Edit: actually there's a "feature request" ticket open for this, and you can just vote on it to express your support, or add a comment if you have additional use cases: https://www.blackberry.com/jira/browse/TABLET-432

Comment: I have already contacted them and waiting for their response.

Comment: Bassem, see my edited answer for a link to the feature request for this.

Answer (score 1):

Root your playbook, then enter a ssh console and remove the system event listener for the bottom bezel swipe gesture. 
I imagine this would be fun